# Dagger 2 MissingBinding when swapping concretion for interface

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have two classes that I'm able to have Dagger find and inject for me to use successfully:

**TrackEvent**

```
class TrackEvent @Inject constructor(
    private val getTrackingProperties: SomeClass
) : UseCase<Boolean, TrackingEvent> {

    override suspend operator fun invoke(params: TrackingEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
```

**SomeClass** (note: used as a dependency in `TrackEvent`)

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor() {
    override suspend operator fun invoke(): UserTrackingPropertiesResult {
        return UserTrackingPropertiesResult()
    }
}
```

`TrackEvent` has an entry in an `@Module` annotated interface because it's an implementation of the `UseCase` interface:

```
@Component(modules = [MyModule::class])
interface ShiftsComponent {
    fun inject(homeFragment: HomeFragment)
}

@Module
interface MyModule {

    @Binds
    fun bindsTrackEventUseCase(useCase: TrackEvent): UseCase<Boolean, TrackingEvent>
}
```

**Use Case interfaces**

```
interface UseCase<out T, in P> {

    suspend operator fun invoke(params: P): T
}

interface NoParamUseCase<out T> {

    suspend operator fun invoke(): T
}
```

What I'd like to do is to inject an interface into `TrackEvent` instead of the concrete `SomeClass`. So I make `SomeClass` implement a `NoParamUseCase`

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor(): NoParamUseCase<UserTrackingPropertiesResult> {
    override suspend operator fun invoke(): UserTrackingPropertiesResult {
        return UserTrackingPropertiesResult()
    }
}
```

update `TrackEvent` to inject the interface:

```
class TrackEvent @Inject constructor(
    private val getTrackingProperties: NoParamUseCase<UserTrackingPropertiesResult>) : UseCase<Boolean, TrackingEvent> {

    override suspend operator fun invoke(params: TrackingEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

…and update `MyModule` to inform Dagger of which implementation I'd like to use:

```
@Module
interface MyModule {

    @Binds
    fun bindsTrackEventUseCase(useCase: TrackEvent): UseCase<Boolean, TrackingEvent>

    // New
    @Binds
    fun bindsSomeClass(useCase: SomeClass): NoParamUseCase<UserTrackingPropertiesResult>
}
```

Dagger now claims that there is a missing binding and that I need to declare an `@Provides` annotated method:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.myapp.core.domain.usecase.NoParamUseCase<? extends com.myapp.core.tracking.UserTrackingPropertiesResult> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface MyComponent {
                ^
      com.myapp.core.domain.usecase.NoParamUseCase<? extends com.myapp.core.tracking.UserTrackingPropertiesResult> is injected at
          com.myapp.tasks.tracking.domain.usecase.TrackEvent(getTrackingProperties, …)
          …
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't true:

- While, I've opted for `@Binds` in this instance, replacing this with `@Provides` and manually providing dependencies here yields the same error.
- I'm using the exact same approach for the `TrackEvent` class and this works.
- The *only* thing I've changed is that I'd like to provide an interface instead. I'd fully understand this error had I not provided the `@Binds` declaration.

This is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953933/dagger-2-two-provides-method-that-provide-same-interface) as there's no ambiguity as to which implementation I'm asking Dagger to use in the way that there would be if I had two or more implementations of the same interface.

Why would I get this error now?

Comment: is GetUser already provide? or has constructor inject?

Comment: @hai I've removed all of the additional dependencies now. They weren't relevant and the issue still persists even in this simplified form.

Comment: @HBG, to solve problem try add `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to the signature of function inside your DI module like this `@Binds fun bindsSomeClass(useCase: SomeClass): NoParamUseCase<@JvmSuppressWildcards UserTrackingPropertiesResult>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dagger 2 - two provides method that provide same interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953933/dagger-2-two-provides-method-that-provide-same-interface)

Comment: Dagger doesn't know which implementation to provide for that interface with just a `@binds` annotation. You need to explicitly tell dagger if you don't want to write a `@provides` concrete function. To do that you need to either add a `@named` annotation or your own custom `@qualifier`

Comment: @sonnet Thanks but this didn't seem to have any impact. I've a number of similar places in the code where I've needed to be more specific about which implementation I'd like Dagger to use - this doesn't appear to be one of them. I only have one implementation that adheres to this type. Nonetheless, I tried your solution and it made no impact.

Comment: @ConstOrVar  Adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` does indeed seem to solve the issue - but not when added to the Module. It only works when added to `TrackEvent` directly: `val getTrackingProperties:NoParamUseCase<@JvmSuppressWildcards UserTrackingPropertiesResult>`. Does `UserTrackingPropertiesResult` being a `sealed class` have some sort of impact here?

Comment: @HBG I think, it relates to how kotlin and dagger compiler work in conjunction in case of generation code for generics. Will it helps if you modify `@Binds fun bindsSomeClass(useCase: SomeClass): NoParamUseCase<out UserTrackingPropertiesResult>` - explicitly adding `out` modifier?

Comment: @ConstOrVar The `out` variance is already specified on the interface so this has no effect. Would you like to provide an answer with the above and claim the points/ glory?

Comment: @HBG, I've investigated a little bit and found solution to that problem: `@Binds
    fun bindsSomeClass(useCase: SomeClass): NoParamUseCase<@JvmWildcard UserTrackingPropertiesResult>` - this instructs kotlin compiler to generate appropriate signature to resolve dependencies. In my test project it helps to eliminate the issue. And that solution allow to not modify your target classes, only DI specific module. If it'll resolve problem, give me feedback and I post it as answer with advanced explanation

Comment: @ConstOrVar Yes, this works and prevents me from having to modify the injection site. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to dagger error message, it expects covariant type `NoParamUseCase<? extends UserTrackingPropertiesResult>`, but DI module provides invariant `NoParamUseCase<UserTrackingPropertiesResult>`. To generate appropriate signature for *provide* method you can change it like this:

```
@Binds fun bindsSomeClass(useCase: SomeClass): NoParamUseCase<@JvmWildcard UserTrackingPropertiesResult>
```

After that your code should be compiled successfully.