# Dagger 2 providing different interface implementation is causing errors

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm new in Dagger dependency injection. I have this interface implemented in two different classes:

```
interface TaskCardContract {
    interface View{
        fun setDescription(description: String)
        fun setSubTitle(subTitle: String)
        fun setIcon(iconId: Int)
        fun setAction(actionToExecute: () -> Unit)
        fun configureUi()
    }

    interface Presenter{
        fun attachView(view: android.view.View)
        fun setAction(actionToExecute: () -> Unit)
        fun executeAction()
    }
}
```

These are the classes:

```
class TaskCardPresenter : TaskCardContract.Presenter {
    private lateinit var taskCard: TaskCard
    private var taskAction: (() -> Unit)? = null

    override fun setAction(actionToExecute: () -> Unit) {
        ...
    }

    override fun executeAction() {
        ...
    }

    override fun attachView(view: android.view.View){
        ...
    }
}

class TaskReservationCardPresenter : TaskCardContract.Presenter {
    private lateinit var taskCard: TaskReservationCard
    private var taskAction: (() -> Unit)? = null

    override fun setAction(actionToExecute: () -> Unit) {
        ...
    }

    override fun executeAction() {
        ...
    }

    override fun attachView(view: android.view.View){
        ...
    }
}
```

Reading this [post](http://Dagger%202%20:%20error%20while%20getting%20a%20multiple%20instances%20of%20same%20object%20with%20@Named) I inserted @Named tag in both implementations of my module and in classes when they are injected:

```
open class TaskCard : ConstraintLayout, TaskCardContract.View{
    @Inject
    @Named("TaskCardViewPresenter")
    lateinit var presenter: TaskCardContract.Presenter
    ...
}

class TaskReservationCard : ConstraintLayout, TaskCardContract.View {
    ...
    private var reservationHandler: ReservationHandler? = null

    @Inject
    @Named("TaskReservationCardPresenter")
    lateinit var reservationPresenter: TaskCardContract.Presenter
    ...
}

@Module
class ViewModule(private val view: View){
    ...
    @Provides
    @Named("TaskCardViewPresenter")
    fun providesTaskCardViewPresenter() : TaskCardContract.Presenter = TaskCardPresenter()

    @Provides
    @Named("TaskReservationCardPresenter")
    fun providesTaskReservationCardPresenter() : TaskCardContract.Presenter = TaskReservationCardPresenter()
    ...
}
```

And this is when they are declare for injection. The ViewModule is a Subcomponent:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [ViewModule::class])
interface ViewComponent {
    fun inject(taskCard: TaskCard)
    fun inject(taskReservationCard: TaskReservationCard)
    ...
}
```

Even with the @Named tag, Dagger complains about @Provides tag. Log information:

```
error: [com.di.ViewComponent.inject(com.ui.taskcard.TaskCard)] com.ui.taskcard.TaskCardContract.Presenter cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      com.ui.taskcard.TaskCardContract.Presenter is injected at
          com.ui.taskcard.TaskCard.presenter
```

What do I need to do to Dagger injects both implementations?

Comment: Please add Dagger's related Component and modules where all these @Provides are.

Comment: @karandhillon Ok. Question updated.

Comment: Your ViewModule is not formatted. Also add the error log please.

Answer (score 0):

After digging for more answers, I found out kotlin needs to do named injection in a different way:

```
@field:[Inject Named("TaskReservationCardPresenter")]
    lateinit var reservationPresenter: TaskCardContract.Presenter

@field:[Inject Named("TaskCardViewPresenter")]
    lateinit var presenter: TaskCardContract.Presenter
```

This solves the problem. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953933/dagger-2-two-provides-method-that-provide-same-interface).

Comment: Sounds like you're using an _old_ Dagger version. Should work fine with 2.25+ IIRC